# R: Select first and last rows of a group of emissions (one visit) and distinguish between different visits at same location

Tags: r, duplicates

Working with some data on a migratory species of birds, zarapitos (genus *Numenius*), that go from Alaska, USA to Maullín, Chile. They stop to rest and feed on a group of islands in Chiloé. Trying to figure out how measure the amount of time they are spending on each island. The data is something like this: 
Column a is time (recordings from a GPS) and column b represents where the zarapito is. This is either outside of any of the sites ("o"), in site 1 ("s1"), or site 2 ("s2"). I want to figure out how to pick out the first and last row of of each group of emissions. In the example below I would want to pull out rows 5 (the first recording we have of the zarapito at site 2) and 7 (the last recording in site 2) in order to get the difference in time (05:39 - 03:21). And then again when the zarapito is at site 1 two times (12:17 to 16:48 and 17:58 to 18:42). The actual data has the zarapito going between a number of different sites and returning to the same ones a bunch of times.

Was trying to use an `ifelse` statement to select only those rows that for which the following or previous row was the same for column "site" but I don't know how to remove the duplicates (Eg. Select rows 5 and 7 without 6) and also distinguish between when the zarapito visits at site 1 at 03:21, again at 12:17, and again at 17:58. In this example I don't care whether the emission at 02:34 (row 4) is included or not (would not use this emission because it's by itself).

Also feel free to suggest title changes to get better responses.

```
 ------------------
  | time   | site |
 ------------------
 1| 00:12  | o    |
 2| 00:15  | o    |
 3| 00:57  | o    |
 4| 02:34  | s1   |
 5| 03:21  | s2   |
 6| 05:12  | s2   |
 7| 05:39  | s2   |
 8| 07:18  | o    |
 9| 10:44  | o    |
10| 12:17  | s1   |
11| 12:49  | s1   |
12| 12:57  | s1   |
13| 15:02  | s1   |
14| 16:48  | s1   |
15| 17:13  | o    |
16| 17:58  | s1   |
17| 18:20  | s1   |
18| 18:42  | s1   |
19| 19:12  | o    |
20| 20:07  | o    |
-------------------

df <- data.frame(time=c('00:12','00:15','00:57','02:34','03:21','05:12','05:39','07:18','10:44','12:17','12:49','12:57','15:02','16:48','17:13','17:58','18:20','18:42','19:12','20:07'),site=c('o','o','o','s1','s2','s2','s2','o','o','s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','o','s1','s1','s1','o','o') )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably simpler to do through `data.table`, though it would certainly be possible in base R as well.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, rleid := rleid(site)][site!="o", if(.N > 1) .SD[c(1,.N)], by=rleid]
#   rleid  time site
#1:     3 03:21   s2
#2:     3 05:39   s2
#3:     5 12:17   s1
#4:     5 16:48   s1
#5:     7 17:58   s1
#6:     7 18:42   s1
```

`rleid()` assigns groups based on the successive appearances at each site. Then the code just takes the first `1` and last `.N` rows from each group. Only the groups with more than one row `if(.N > 1)` are returned.

Comment: was just typing up a similar solution... :)

Comment: Yay! Is there a reason that `rleid()` would not be part of `data.table`? I'm sure I've downloaded the package correctly.